# title bar in ubuntu where not visible properly

Tags: 22.04

The title bar text and popup text are not clearly visible in Ubuntu 22.04. Even if I change the font, it does not appear properly.

This is what I see:

[image: title bar]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How can I reproduce this dialog to check how it looks on my system?

Comment: i just move file to another folder it popup on screen